# Schedule by specific date and time in agendajs

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, agenda

I am using agendajs to schedule the jobs.
In docs, it is shown how to schedule jobs like

```
agenda.schedule('in 2 minutes', 'some jobs')
```

How can I schedule the job in specific date and time.
I tried to use like below but didn't work

```
agenda.schedule('at 2018-7-24 09:47')
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs:

> **schedule(when, name, [data], [cb])**
>
> Schedules a job to run name once at a given time. `when` can be a Date
>   or a String such as tomorrow at 5pm.

So something like:

```
agenda.schedule(new Date(), 'MyJob')
```

Should do it.

On the end of the day all this is doing is crating the job and setting the **nextRunAt** ISODate for that job record.